# Webscraping - Selenium - Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, while-loop

I want to extract all the fantasy teams that have been entered for past contests. To loop through the dates, I just change a small part of the URL as shown in my code below:

```
#Packages:

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import pandas as pd


# Driver
chromedriver =("C:/Users/Michel/Desktop/python/package/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

# Dataframe that will be use later 
results = pd.DataFrame()
best_lineups=pd.DataFrame()
opti_lineups=pd.DataFrame()

#For loop over all DATES:

calendar=[]
calendar.append("2019-01-10")
calendar.append("2019-01-11")

for d in calendar:
    driver.get("https://rotogrinders.com/resultsdb/date/"+d+"/sport/4/")
```

Then, to access the different contests of that day, you need to click on the `contest` tab. I use the following code to locate and click on it.

```
 # Find "Contest" tab   
    contest= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='root']/div/main/main/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]")
    contest.click()
```

I simply inspect and copy the xpath of the tab. However, most of the times it is working, but sometimes I get an error message " Unable to locate element...". Moreover, it seems to work only for the first date in my calendar loop and always fails in the next iteration... I do not know why. I try to locate it differently, but I feel I am missing something such as:

```
contests=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@role='tab']
```

Once, the contest tab is successfully clicked, all contests of that day are there and you can click on a link to access all the entries of that contest. I stored the contests in order to iterate throuhg all as follow:

```
    list_links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    hlink=[]
    for ii in list_links:
        hlink.append(ii.get_attribute("href"))
    sub="https://rotogrinders.com/resultsdb"
    con= "contest"
    contest_list=[]
    for text in hlink:
        if sub in text:
            if con in text:
                contest_list.append(text)
# Iterate through all the entries(user) of a contest and extract the information of the team entered by the user 

    for c in contest_list:
        driver.get(c)
```

Then, I want to extract all participants team entered in the contest and store it in a dataframe. I am able to do it successfully for the first page of the contest.

```
# Waits until tables are loaded and has text. Timeouts after 60 seconds
        while WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, './/tbody//tr//td//span//a[text() != ""]'))):

# while ????: 

# Get tables to get the user names
            tables = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
            users_df  = tables[0][['Rank','User']]
            users_df['User'] = users_df['User'].str.replace(' Member', '')

# Initialize results dataframe and iterate through users

            for i, row in users_df.iterrows():

                rank = row['Rank']
                user = row['User']

    # Find the user name and click on the name
                user_link = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[text()='%s']" %(user))[0]
                user_link.click()

    # Get the lineup table after clicking on the user name
                tables = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
                lineup = tables[1]

    #print (user)
    #print (lineup)

    # Restructure to put into resutls dataframe
                lineup.loc[9, 'Name'] = lineup.iloc[9]['Salary']
                lineup.loc[10, 'Name'] = lineup.iloc[9]['Pts']

                temp_df = pd.DataFrame(lineup['Name'].values.reshape(-1, 11), 
                columns=lineup['Pos'].iloc[:9].tolist() + ['Total_$', 'Total_Pts'] )

                temp_df.insert(loc=0, column = 'User', value = user)
                temp_df.insert(loc=0, column = 'Rank', value = rank)
                temp_df["Date"]=d
                results = results.append(temp_df)
            #next_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@type='button']")
            #next_button[2].click()



            results = results.reset_index(drop=True)



driver.close()
```

However, there are other pages and to access it, you need to click on the small arrow `next button`at the bottom. Moreover, you can click indefinitely on that button; even if there are not more entries. Therefore, I would like to be able to loop through all pages with entries and stop when there are no more entries and change contest. I try to implement a while loop to do so, but my code did not work...

Answer (score 0):

You must really make sure that page loads completely before you do anything on that page.

> Moreover, it seems to work only for the first date in my calendar loop
>   and always fails in the next iteration

Usually when selenium loads a browser page it tries to look for the element even if it is not loaded all the way. I suggest you to recheck the *xpath* of the element you are trying to click.

Also try to see when the page loads completely and use `time.sleep(number of seconds)`
to make sure you hit the element or you can check for a particular element or a property of element that would let you know that the page has been loaded.

One more suggestion is that you can use `driver.current_url` to see which page are you targetting. I have had this issue while i was working on multiple tabs and I had to tell python/selenium to manually switch to that tab